# How to start the Omega DLC?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I have just got the Omega DLC for Mass Effect 3 and it isn't particularly obvious how to start it. I have checked the Galaxy map for any markers and all that is left on my map is the final mission and the remainder of the Leviathan DLC:

[image]

I have also tried visiting Aria on the Citadel, but she just provides the normal conversational options from pre-DLC.

Do I need to start a fresh game to access the Omega DLC, or is it that I haven't finished the Leviathan DLC that is preventing me from accessing the new content?

Is there anything else that I am missing?

Comment: Just commenting to say this question helped me out. It's always so annoying with DLC's.

You part with your hard-earned cash and download the DLC, start up the game, and then you're in purgatory (pun intended) for a good ten minutes wondering where the hell your stuff is...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had no trouble doing this on a save halfway through the game, with Leviathan halfway done to boot.  You'll get an email from Aria, and then it should show up on the Citadel with a marker the same way Leviathan did.  *You may have to read this email first* - I didn't check to see if showed up anyway on mine.

You will need to complete Aria's original missions from Mass Effect 3 (uniting the Blood Pack, Blue Suns, and Eclipse) before the Omega DLC missions become available.

Comment: Thanks - I went off and finished the Leviathan DLC and then read my mail and it was there, I didn't check it before hand so I'm guessing it was just a case of reading my mail!

Comment: I still have the same problem. I've re-downloaded about 3 times now, no joy.

Answer (score 3):

You have to finish Priority Palaven first.

You will then get the invite email from Aria. When you head for the Citadel you will see two docking choices - one for the normal landing bay and a new one for another landing bay (the one that Aria gives in her email) Choose the new bay and you are good to go!

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't gotten the blue suns, blood pack, and eclipse together it won't let you do the mission. Once you have done this then omega should come up on your email.